# Device Language effect on app language

Tags: java, android

I have android app with two language English and  Arabic and i change app language like this:

```
public void setLocale() {
    if (SharedPreferencesHelper.getSharedPreferencesInt(this, AppConstant.LANGUAGE, AppConstant.LANGUAGE_EN_MFQ) == AppConstant.LANGUAGE_AR_MFQ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
        Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } else {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

When device language is English and app language English, the app work perfectly but, when the app is in Arabic and the device is English some of fragment give wrong language, or some of views like text in Arabic and another text in English at same fragment, this is my issue, how i can  solve this ?

Comment: Did you make strings.xml files for all labels and languages?

Comment: Did you define all strings in values-ar as well as in values?

Comment: Hard-coded strings may also be the problem.

Comment: yes i do this and i sure because sometimes the app working in arabic and good

Comment: Please show the XML of the different labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer for your problem, but I will tell you how I managed to create an app with English/Arabic languages.

I used the `LocaleHelper.java` class from this blog post: [Change Language Programmatically in Android](https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/)

And created a custom Activity class (overriding the base context) as base class for all activities in the app

```
public class MyAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, LocaleHelper.LOCALE_DEFAULT_LANG));
    }

}
```

It's working great for me, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. For

> when the app is in Arabic and the device is English some of fragment give wrong language

Your app will pick the strings in default 
`values` folder or `values-en`. So you need to put the English  strings in your normal `values/strings.xml` or `values-en/strings.xml` file.

For device language Arabic You need to make a folder `values-ar`, and translate all strings to Arabic and put the `strings.xml` file containing Arabic strings in this folder.
You need to look for any hard coded strings and put them in `strings.xml` files.

Comment: i have string-ar and string-en my issue that sometimes locale change automatically !!